# Hibernate validation: validate PI

Tags: bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I'm in need to apply a validation on a double value which needs to match with PI. I'm thinking to use a **@Pattern(regex="3.14159265359")**. Is it the best way I can apply such a constraint using Hibernate Validation Constraints?
Thanks

Comment: This regex will match "3A14159265359", since `.` has special meaning (any character), so it's probably not the right choice. Why do you need to have this on your object/validate it anyway? PI is a constant, it can't be changed, so I don't really see a use case where having it as some mutable field which you're going to validate would be of any use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Pattern` is only defined for string type (`CharSequence` really). If your data type is a double you cannot use it, unless you write a custom `ConstraintValidator`. You could use `DecimalMin` in combination with `DecimalMax` potentially allowing for some imprecision. Alternatively, you could write your own constraint `@Pi` which for example allows to specify a delta. `@Pi` is probably the best solution, provided you really need this validation.